# xFormers can't load C++/CUDA extensions

Tags: google-colaboratory

Issue:  WARNING[XFORMERS]: xFormers can't load C++/CUDA extensions. xFormers was built for:
PyTorch 2.1.0+cu121 with CUDA 1202 (you have 2.2.1+cu121)
Python  3.10.12 (you have 3.10.12)
Please reinstall xformers (see https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers#installing-xformers)

Describe: I am a new user of Colab Pro. I could quickly run Fast SD Automatic1111 yesterday. However, I ran across a problem with xformers today (please see above).

I tried "!pip3 install -U xformers --index-url [https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121"](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121%22) But it showed errors also as below:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchaudio 2.2.1+cu121 requires torch==2.2.1, but you have torch 2.2.0+cu121 which is incompatible.
torchtext 0.17.1 requires torch==2.2.1, but you have torch 2.2.0+cu121 which is incompatible.
torchvision 0.17.1+cu121 requires torch==2.2.1, but you have torch 2.2.0+cu121 which is incompatible.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look for xFormers corresponding to PyTorch 2.1.0+cu121. This is the comparison website: [https://anaconda.org/xformers/xformers/files][1]

1. reset torch version to 2.2.1+cu121

   pip install torch==2.2.1+cu121 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

2.install the corresponding xformers

```
!pip install xformers==0.0.26.dev767
```

Comment: Richard, could you please also send me a code to check the versions and status of all components on the notebook, ie torch, torchversion, torchaudio, torchtext, xformers, etc.? Many thanks!